# How to get first-time output out of a richedit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

I have a problem when my code outputs to a rich edit. When I click on the button to calculate everything and then display everything it doesn't output the generated ClientNum and Price. However, when I click the button for a second time afterwards it outputs everything without a cinch? Is there a problem with my code or could be something external like an anti-virus software that's messing with the output?

Images to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]


My code:

```
    type
  TfrmTourBooking = class(TForm)
    rgpDestination: TRadioGroup;
    rgpAccommodation: TRadioGroup;
    sedPeopleAmount: TSpinEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    edtID: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    redOut: TRichEdit;
    btnCalc: TButton;
    bmbClose: TBitBtn;
    rgpTransport: TRadioGroup;
    edtName: TEdit;
    Label4: TLabel;
    rgpTourLength: TRadioGroup;
    edtPhoneNum: TLabeledEdit;
    edtEmail: TLabeledEdit;
    bmbReset: TBitBtn;
    dtpTime: TDateTimePicker;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgpDestinationClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgpTourLengthClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure rgpAccommodationClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure bmbResetClick(Sender: TObject);
    function GetFinalPriceWithVAT : real;
    function toString : string;
    const
    vatRate = 0.15;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    objGeneralRetrieval:TGenRet;
    sDBName,sDBMail,sDBID,sDBPhone,sDBBirth:string;
    iDBPeople:integer;
    rTranPrice:real;
    arrDestinations: array [0..5] of string;
    arrDestPrice: array [0..5] of integer;
    specialArray: array [1..10] of char;
    procedure DatabasePrep;
    procedure CasesForRadioGroups;
    procedure Validations;
    procedure ValidationForPeopleAmount;
    procedure ValidationForID;
    procedure ValidationForEmail;
    procedure ValidationForName;
    procedure ValidationForPhoneNum;
    procedure ValidationForDOB;
    procedure RadioCheck;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    iPeopleAmount:integer;
    sBookName,sID,sPhoneNum,sEmail,sDOB,sDestName:string;
    sClientNum:string;
    sAccPrint,sTransportPrint,sTLP:string;
    rPrelimPrice:real;
    rPriceWithVAT:real;
    rPrice:real;
  end;

var
  frmTourBooking: TfrmTourBooking;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


//this button resets the form
procedure TfrmTourBooking.bmbResetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

//re-disable the radiogroups
rgpTourLength.Enabled:=False;
rgpTransport.Enabled:=False;
rgpAccommodation.Enabled:=False;

//reset the inputs
edtID.Clear;
dtpTime.Date:=Date;
edtName.Clear;
edtPhoneNum.Clear;
edtEmail.Clear;
rgpDestination.ItemIndex:= -1;
rgpAccommodation.ItemIndex:= -1;
rgpTransport.ItemIndex:= -1;
rgpTourLength.ItemIndex:= -1;
sedPeopleAmount.Value:= 0;

//clear the output
redOut.Clear;

end;

//this button calculates everything and gives an output afterwards
procedure TfrmTourBooking.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Validations;
  CasesForRadioGroups;
  redOut.lines.Add(toString);
  DatabasePrep;
end;

//validates all the inputs
procedure TfrmTourBooking.Validations;

begin

  //people amount check
  ValidationForPeopleAmount;
  //ID check
  ValidationForID;
  //Email check
  ValidationForEmail;
  //Name check
  ValidationForName;
  //phone number check
  ValidationForPhoneNum;
  //DOB check
  ValidationForDOB;
  //if none of the options on the radio groups are checked
  RadioCheck;

end;



//the seperate validation procedures
procedure TfrmTourBooking.ValidationForPeopleAmount;
begin

  if (sedPeopleAmount.Value < 1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error: please enter a valid amount of people going on the tour');
    //disable the radiogroups
    rgpTourLength.Enabled := False;
    rgpTransport.Enabled := False;
    rgpAccommodation.Enabled := False;
    //reset the inputs
    edtID.Clear;
    edtName.Clear;
    edtPhoneNum.Clear;
    edtEmail.Clear;
    dtpTime.Date:=Date;
    rgpDestination.ItemIndex := -1;
    rgpAccommodation.ItemIndex := -1;
    rgpTransport.ItemIndex := -1;
    rgpTourLength.ItemIndex := -1;
    sedPeopleAmount.Value := 0;
    //clear the output
    redOut.Clear;
  end;

  if (sedPeopleAmount.Value > 30) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error: please enter a valid amount of people going on the tour');
    //disable the radiogroups
    rgpTourLength.Enabled := False;
    rgpTransport.Enabled := False;
    rgpAccommodation.Enabled := False;
    //reset the inputs
    edtID.Clear;
    edtName.Clear;
    edtPhoneNum.Clear;
    edtEmail.Clear;
    rgpDestination.ItemIndex := -1;
    rgpAccommodation.ItemIndex := -1;
    rgpTransport.ItemIndex := -1;
    rgpTourLength.ItemIndex := -1;
    sedPeopleAmount.Value := 0;
    //clear the output
    redOut.Clear;
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.ValidationForID;
var
  iIDLength: integer;
  c:char;
  i: Integer;
begin
  iIDLength := Length(edtID.Text);

  //array of special characters
  specialArray[1]:= '@';
  specialArray[2]:= '!';
  specialArray[3]:= '#';
  specialArray[4]:= '$';
  specialArray[5]:= '%';
  specialArray[6]:= '^';
  specialArray[7]:= '&';
  specialArray[8]:= '*';
  specialArray[9]:= '(';
  specialArray[10]:= ')';
  //end of array

  if (iIDLength = 13) then
  begin

    for c in sID do
    begin
      for i := 1 to 10 do
      begin

      if c = specialArray[i] then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Error: invalid format');
          //disable the radiogroups
        rgpTourLength.Enabled := False;
        rgpTransport.Enabled := False;
        rgpAccommodation.Enabled := False;
        //reset the inputs
        edtID.Clear;
        edtName.Clear;
        edtPhoneNum.Clear;
        edtEmail.Clear;
        rgpDestination.ItemIndex := -1;
        rgpAccommodation.ItemIndex := -1;
        rgpTransport.ItemIndex := -1;
        rgpTourLength.ItemIndex := -1;
        sedPeopleAmount.Value := 0;
        //clear the output
        redOut.Clear;
      end;

      end;
    end;

  end;
end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.ValidationForEmail;
begin

end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.ValidationForName;
begin

end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.ValidationForPhoneNum;
begin

end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.ValidationForDOB;
begin

end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.RadioCheck;
begin

end;
//end of validation procedures



//outputs everything to the rich edit
function TfrmTourBooking.toString : string;
var
firstLine,secondLine,thirdLine,fourthLine,fifthLine:string;
output:string;
begin
  iPeopleAmount:= sedPeopleAmount.Value;
  sEmail:=edtEmail.Text;
  sDOB:=DateToStr(dtpTime.Date);
  sBookName:=edtName.Text;
  sID:=edtID.Text;
  sPhoneNum:=edtPhoneNum.Text;
  rPrice:= GetFinalPriceWithVAT;
  firstLine:= 'QUOTATION FOR: '+ sClientNum + #13+#13+'Amount of people going on the tour: '+ IntToStr(iPeopleAmount) + #13 + #13 ;
  secondLine:='CLIENT DETAILS: '+ #13 + 'Name of booker: '+ sBookName + #13 + 'DOB: ' + sDOB + #13 + 'ID number: '+ sID + #13 + 'Contact Number: '+ sPhoneNum +#13+ 'Email: '+ sEmail + #13 + #13;
  thirdLine:= 'TOUR DETAILS: ' + #13 + 'Destination: ' + sDestName + #13 + 'Tour Length: '+ sTLP +#13+ 'Transport type: ' + sTransportPrint + #13 + 'Accomodation: '+ sAccPrint + #13 + #13;
  fourthLine:= 'PRICING: ' + #13 + FloatToStrF(rPrice,ffCurrency,6,2)+ #13;
  fifthLine:= #13 + '©The Travel Agency 2020';
  output:= firstLine + secondLine + thirdLine + fourthLine + fifthLine;
  Result:= output;
end;

//this procedure is to handle the nitty gritty of the database input
procedure TfrmTourBooking.DatabasePrep;
begin
  //create the object
  objGeneralRetrieval := TGenRet.Create(edtName.Text, edtID.Text, edtPhoneNum.Text, sedPeopleAmount.Value, edtEmail.Text);

  //get variables for db input from object
  sDBName:=objGeneralRetrieval.GetName;
  sDBID:=objGeneralRetrieval.GetID;
  sDBMail:=objGeneralRetrieval.GetEmail;
  sDBPhone:=objGeneralRetrieval.GetPhoneNum;
  iDBPeople:=objGeneralRetrieval.GetPeopleAmount;
  sDBBirth:=sDOB;
  sClientNum := AnsiUpperCase(objGeneralRetrieval.GetClientNum);

  //destroy object when done
  objGeneralRetrieval.Free;
end;

//this procedure is for the multiple radio groups' outcomes
procedure TfrmTourBooking.CasesForRadioGroups;
var
  iBasePrice: Integer;
  rMultiplied: Real;
  rAdded: Real;
begin
  iBasePrice:=0;
  rMultiplied:=0;
  rAdded:=0;
  //the starting prices
  arrDestPrice[1]:=4000;
  arrDestPrice[2]:=5000;
  arrDestPrice[3]:=2500;
  arrDestPrice[4]:=3000;
  arrDestPrice[5]:=1950;

  //when you choose the destination
  case (rgpDestination.ItemIndex) of
    0:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[1];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[1];
      end;
    1:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[2];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[2];
      end;
    2:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[3];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[3];
      end;
    3:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[4];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[4];
      end;
    4:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[5];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[5];
      end;
  end;

  //When you choose the length of the tour
  case (rgpTourLength.ItemIndex) of
    0:
      begin
        rMultiplied := (iBasePrice * 1.5);
        sTLP:='3 days';
      end;
    1:
      begin
        rMultiplied := (iBasePrice * 2);
        sTLP:='5 days';
      end;
    2:
      begin
        rMultiplied := (iBasePrice * 2.5);
        sTLP:='7 days';
      end;
  end;

  //When you choose the accommodation
  case (rgpAccommodation.ItemIndex) of
    0:
      begin
        rAdded := 1500;
        sAccPrint:='Hotel';
      end;
    1:
      begin
        rAdded := 850;
        sAccPrint:='Guesthouse';
      end;
    2:
      begin
        rAdded := 0;
        sAccPrint:='Own Accommodation';
      end;
  end;

  //When you choose a mode of transport
  case (rgpTransport.ItemIndex) of
    0:
      begin
        rTranPrice := 1000;
        sTransportPrint:='Bus';
      end;
    1:
      begin
        rTranPrice := 3000;
        sTransportPrint:='Flight';
      end;
    2:
      begin
        rTranPrice := 0;
        sTransportPrint:='Own Transport';
      end;
  end;

 rPrelimPrice:= (rMultiplied + rAdded + rTranPrice) * iPeopleAmount;

end;

//to calculate the final price with VAT
function TfrmTourBooking.GetFinalPriceWithVAT : real;
var
vat:real;
begin
vat:= rPrelimPrice * vatRate;
rPriceWithVAT := vat + rPrelimPrice;
Result:= rPriceWithVAT;
end;

//this is when the form starts
procedure TfrmTourBooking.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
//disable other radio groups than destination at startup
rgpTourLength.Enabled:=False;
rgpAccommodation.Enabled:=False;
rgpTransport.Enabled:=False;

//array initialize
arrDestinations[1]:='Cape Town';
arrDestinations[2]:='Camps Bay';
arrDestinations[3]:='Mossel Bay';
arrDestinations[4]:='Knysna';
arrDestinations[5]:='Oudtshoorn';
//end of array initialize

end;


//these are to disable the radio groups until the previous group is clicked
procedure TfrmTourBooking.rgpAccommodationClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
rgpTransport.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.rgpDestinationClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
rgpTourLength.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure TfrmTourBooking.rgpTourLengthClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
rgpAccommodation.Enabled:=True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It is because you call `DatabasePrep` after `toString` in `btnCalcClick`. Shouldn't it be the other way around? Maybe today is a good day to learn how to use debugger and breakpoints. It saves you time pasting walls of code to SO and waiting for an answer ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have a look at your button-click handler, which is responsible for populating the Rich Edit control:

```
procedure TfrmTourBooking.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Validations;
  CasesForRadioGroups;
  redOut.lines.Add(toString);
  DatabasePrep;
end;
```

If you look at your `toString` method, which is the one creating your output, you see that it uses the public `sClientNum` field.

When do you actually set this variable? It is only set once, in `DatabasePrep`. So before you have run `DatabasePrep`, this string will be the empty string (because class fields are always initialized).

So, when do you call `DatabasePrep`? You only call it in `btnCalcClick`, *but only after you have populated the Rich Edit control*.

Consequently, the first time you click the button, you will get the output with the empty string, and the second time you get the full output.

---

There are other issues in your code:

- You should [refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) it, especially to [avoid repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). For instance, you should create a `ResetForm` method.
- Every time you create an object, you must protect it to avoid memory leaks:

  ```
  procedure TfrmTourBooking.DatabasePrep;
  begin

    objGeneralRetrieval := TGenRet.Create(edtName.Text, edtID.Text, edtPhoneNum.Text, sedPeopleAmount.Value, edtEmail.Text);
    try
      sDBName := objGeneralRetrieval.GetName;
      sDBID := objGeneralRetrieval.GetID;
      sDBMail := objGeneralRetrieval.GetEmail;
      sDBPhone := objGeneralRetrieval.GetPhoneNum;
      iDBPeople := objGeneralRetrieval.GetPeopleAmount;
      sDBBirth := sDOB;
      sClientNum := AnsiUpperCase(objGeneralRetrieval.GetClientNum);
    finally
      objGeneralRetrieval.Free;
     end;

  end;
  ```
- The `objGeneralRetrieval` variable is only used in `DatabasePrep`, so it should be a local variable there. It is dangerous to have it as a class field, especially since it will be a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) after you freed the object without setting the pointer to `nil`.
- On the Microsoft Windows platform, the [newline sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is CRLF: `#13#10`

---

Some other hints:

- `specialArray` should be a constant, not a variable:

  ```
  const
    SpecialChars: array[1..10] of Char = '@!#$%^&*()';
  ```
- When you iterate over this array, you do `for i := 1 to 10 do`. But what if you add a new special character and forget to update this `for` loop line? Better to do `for i := Low(SpecialChars) to High(SpecialChars)`. Even better to use a `for..in` loop.
- This code:

  ```
  case (rgpDestination.ItemIndex) of
    0:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[1];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[1];
      end;
    1:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[2];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[2];
      end;
    2:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[3];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[3];
      end;
    3:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[4];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[4];
      end;
    4:
      begin
        iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[5];
        sDestName := arrDestinations[5];
      end;
  end;
  ```

  could be written more succinctly:

  ```
  if rgpDestination.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    iBasePrice := arrDestPrice[rgpDestination.ItemIndex + 1];
    sDestName := arrDestinations[rgpDestination.ItemIndex + 1];
  end;
  ```

  Less code is easier to read and reason about. Less risk of silly typos.

Comment: Thanks so much for all this info! Really appreciate it! I'm not so well acquainted with debugging as it isn't really covered in the syllabus we have, but thanks for reminding me of it!